# Getting 500 error in PayPal REST API

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I'm using "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" in my PHP application, been testing perfectly in the sandbox for past month.  Moved to LIVE tonight to finish pre-prod testing and now getting this response.

```
[03-12-2014 01:46:32] PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: FINE: Response : {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"9a4e0771d4d79"}
```

Any suggestions as I have searched and not found a suitable answer.

Here is the payload I'm sending (removed URL returns for safety)

```
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: FINE: Payload : 
{"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"redirect_urls":
{"return_url":"XXX","cancel_url":"XXX"},"transactions":
[{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"37.50","details":
{"shipping":"0.00","handling_fee":"2.50","tax":"0.00","subtotal":"35.00"}},"item_list":
{"items":[{"name":"Full Event","description":"This is a full event membership","sku":"547e5ff327a7c","currency":"USD","quantity":1,"price":"35.00"}]},"description":
"Purchase from Site","invoice_number":"547e69aad333b"}]}
```

Comment: Typically Internal Server Error in PayPal REST API is caused by the JSON payload that does not follow correct format. Which operation you are trying to run?

Comment: Why would I not see these errors in the sandbox then during testing?

Comment: Looks like the item description from your request exceeds the maximum number of characters, can you post your complete API request?

Comment: What is the maximum?  I will do a substr(x,0,?) to fix

Comment: I added a substr to the item desc and it fixed the issue, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: glad it worked, added answer , might help somebody someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the item description from your request exceeds the maximum number of characters, can you post your complete API request.
This is the error from the logs for this transaction

`value too large for column ITEM_DESCRIPTION (actual: 142, maximum: 100),`

Comment: Thanks again for the help, wish the error returns were more descriptive for paypal :D

Comment: There are few limitations to what data can we show in the UI page when an exception happens. This prevents us from accidently leaking sensitive data on a normal webpage, which could be seen by anyone. 

Checking the logs are the best way to get the entire description of the actual exception.

But I agree, it should not return 500 exception, it should be 400 with proper text. I will test this out, and create an internal ticket to follow up on this.

Comment: Thanks Vimal & Jay, I love the paypal API and happy it works so well.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I was able to run the samples with a very long text, and it worked just fine on sandbox.

[image]